# Secure and SEO friendly method to return to the previous working page after login in PHP

Tags: php

What is the Secure and SEO friendly method for redirecting a user to the previous page he was working in PHP. 
I have seen people using GET variables to pass url, and I also know that sessions or `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, can be used. But one of my friend told that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not safe
If it is not safe how can we get the previous page URL

Comment: Just pass the current url to login page while redirecting as if in `returnUrl` parameter.

Comment: @Rikesh Which will be just as secure as using http_referer.

Comment: define "Secure" please.

Comment: @Katrin Raimond  By secure I mean, is there a source of attack in any of this method or the values form these variables always trusted...

Comment: @RanjithKuamrKR `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is generated by the client so you should not trust it.

Comment: So how should we find the previous page url.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Friend is right . `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not guarantied to return previous page accurately. My recommendation is to use session and cookie to store the last page. Upon the login check for stored page URL and forward to your desired page and expire the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the previous (relative or absolute) URL via GET (urlencode) to the login page, when you redirect to login.

The HTTP_REFERRER solution is not really secure.

Comment: But is passing via GET and SEO friendly method, as it can makes multiple urls for the same page in many cases.......

Comment: Maybe you can left the GET parameters of the original URL out and set them as array to session. Then you can pass them from login form.